# Pandas plot table is not plotting all the columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot the dataframe which is represented in an image.

```
def count_of_each_categories(self,y_train=None,y_test=None,technology_segment=None):
    """
    :param y_train:
    :param y_test:
    :return:
    """
    df_train = pd.DataFrame()
    df_train[technology_segment] = y_train
    df_test = pd.DataFrame()
    df_train['freq'] = df_train[technology_segment].value_counts()
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['freq'] = df_train[technology_segment].value_counts()

    ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False)  # no visible frame
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis
    # df.plot()
    table(ax, df,cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center',
      loc='top')  # where df is your data frame
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig(r"/Users/nitesh/OneDrive/Work/GE_Python_Workspace/ClassifierApproaches/Excel Documents/"
                 r"Fintech/mytable.png")
```

I am not able to see the technology column, it looks like the image is cropped. [image]

I want to show all the columns present in the dataframe. I have 2 columns in it. 
I am trying to beautify it.

Comment: I don't understand why it is usefull for you to save a dataframe as a figure? Why don't you save it as a csv file instead, then open and transform it with a spreadsheet software and finally print it or do a screen capture ?

Comment: Thanks, David, Right now I am doing the same. However, I will be happy to know if it is possible to do through pandas plot because I am running 200 different models and manually doing it is a time-consuming task.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Are you trying to interpret the result visually or is it for presentation purposes?  In both case you can try to use the `jupyter notebook` [http://jupyter.org/](http://jupyter.org/). It will help you I think

Comment: Thank you david.

Comment: You are welcome ;)